# Understanding free and bounded occurrences of variables

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I was reading chapter 1.5 in A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic when I encountered the following formula in an exercise problem.
$$\forall y (x = y) \lor (\forall x)(x < 0)$$
In this formula, is it true that the first occurrence of x is free and the third x is bounded? What about the second x?

I am just confused about $x$ being free in some occurrences and bounded in others. Does the formula mean exactly the same as $\forall y (x = y) \lor (\forall z)(z < 0)$?

More generally, if a variable is bounded by quantifier $Q_n$ in the formula $\varphi_n$, and all the $Q_1x\varphi_1$ are disjoint subformulas of a formula, would replacing all $x$s in $\varphi_n$ to another variable $x_n$ keep the formula the same?

Comment: You are right about your analysis of $x$. And I would add that this is an exercise in mathematical style: never write a mathematical sentence like that, one which mixes together a free and a bound occurrence of the same variable; you will confuse your readers, as you were confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this formula, is it true that the first occurrence of x is free and the third x is bounded? What about the second x?

Yes, there is no quantifier binding the first occurence of $x$, so it's free. Yes, the third occurence is bounded. The second ocurrence is neither free nor bounded, it's the quantifier itself, and maybe one could, half-seriously, call it a *binding* occurence

> Does the formula mean exactly the same as $∀y(x=y)∨(∀z)(z<0)$?

Yes, it does. Can you figure out why? (Hint: it's not really about 'meaning', but rather about 'use', or "what sorts of formulas can one use this one to infer?")

> More generally, if a variable is bounded by quantifier [...]

Sometimes things get complicated: try to read a bit about "variable capture/capturing"